# How does Spring Data JPA resolve property name containing single letter abbreviation for a word in query methods?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, repository

I've an entity with property name `qYear`. I tried creating a `findByIdAndQYear` method in repository but that did not work. I ran into `IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [QYear] on this ManagedType`).

However `findByIdAndqYear` works. Any idea how single letter abbreviations like this are expanded please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data (not just the JPA module) base this on the Java Bean Specification. 
In order to avoid misinterpretation of the specification this is actually implemented using `[java.beans.Introspector][1]`.

See also https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1589